# How to convert geographic data to CSV

Tags: csv, gis, type-conversion

I am trying to obtain accurate site geometry for a particular location in Autodesk Revit.  The site in question is located near 19621 Waters Road, Germantown MD 20874-0000.  The problem is that I can only import CSV or other comma delimited text, or a CAD format, into Revit, but height data for the region at the nessisary resolution is only available from USGS mational map thingey in ArcGrid, GeoTIFF, GridFloat, and BIL_16INT formats.  I am working on a computer where (because of systemadmin stuff) I can't run any unapproved executables or anything, and my home computer doesn't have Windows, only Ubuntu.  Does anyone know a way to convert the data to what I need, or know of a better whay to obtain this?

Comment: You might have better luck asking your question at http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

If your [ARC GRID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esri_grid) is an ascii file (not binary), don't worry about .asc and just open it in Notepad.
You will find there words *xllcorner*, *yllcorner* and *cellsize*, and values for cell centers. Keywords *xllcorner* and *yllcorner* are coordinates of the low left corner of the grid. (And you need to know what is the coordinate system of the file and if it is the same which you want to import as csv.)

Then you can calculate (for example in Excel) the coordinates of each cell center using *cellsize*. And then write all this in three columns `x,y,value` into a text file *name.csv*.

Comment: Besides, if it will not help, at home on ubuntu you can install free [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) and convert it using [1](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43268/exporting-dem-derived-rasters-to-csv-from-qgis), [2](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22791/how-to-export-a-raster-layer-for-external-processing).

Comment: WHich file in the zip archive is that?  The files I have are a bunch of files with wierd extenstions in a zip.

Comment: Look for a file with .asc extension. If no, try to open the biggest file. If no one has understandable text inside, then it is binary grid, bad luck. Then you need a GIS program like QGIS.

Comment: Actually, I think I may have figured out how to resolve the issue.  Apparently Wolfram Mathmatica (which i have access to from my school) can open gis data formats, so I am using that to convert.

Answer (score 1):

I have a routine that did thins using google earth, VBA and excel... You have to install the google earth developers package but it works pretty well- grabs images off GE and coordinates it with revit VIA a CSV file.

[Revit Tricks Blogspot](http://revittricks.blogspot.com/2013/05/google-earth-revit-and-csv-for-some.html)